# C# Call QRCVDTAQ in AS400 hit Error code 3426

Tags: c#, ibm-midrange

Below is the error detail, Pls help.

```
                 Additional Message Information
```

Message ID . . . . . . :   CPIAD08       Severity . . . . . . . :   40
Message type . . . . . :   Diagnostic
Date sent  . . . . . . :   17/07/26      Time sent  . . . . . . :   14:30:08

Message . . . . :   Host server communications error occurred on recv() -
   length.
Cause . . . . . :   Error code 3426 was received while processing the recv() - 
   length function for the host server communications.
Recovery  . . . :   See any previously listed message(s) to determine the
   cause of the error; if necessary, correct the error and issue the request
   again.

```
                                                                     Bottom
```

Press Enter to continue.

F3=Exit   F6=Print   F9=Display message details   F12=Cancel
F21=Select assistance level

```
                           Display Job Log                                 
                                                         System:   LTAS02
```

Job . . :   QZHQSSRV      User . . :   QUSER         Number . . . :   226264

```
 Job 226264/QUSER/QZHQSSRV started on 17/07/24 at 18:25:13 in subsystem    
   QUSRWRK in QSYS. Job entered system on 17/07/24 at 18:25:13.            
 User DPSGIT from client 10.51.180.171 connected to server.                
 A connection with a remote socket was reset by that socket.               
 Host server communications error occurred on recv() - length.             
 Job 226264/QUSER/QZHQSSRV was ended by user DPSGIT.                       
 Target data queue program job ended abnormally.                           
 Job 226264/QUSER/QZHQSSRV ended on 17/07/26 at 14:30:44; .006 seconds     
   used; end code 50 .            



  /* CLP TEST9100CY*/

   PGM        PARM(&DTAQ &LIB &MSGDTA &KEYS)                       
    DCL        VAR(&DTAQ) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(10)                       
    DCL        VAR(&LIB) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(10)                        
    DCL        VAR(&LENQ) TYPE(*DEC) LEN(5 0) VALUE(1024)           
    DCL        VAR(&MSGDTA) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(1024)                   

    DCL        VAR(&WAIT) TYPE(*DEC) LEN(5 0) VALUE(-1)             
    DCL        VAR(&ORDER) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(2) VALUE('EQ')           
    DCL        VAR(&KEYLEN) TYPE(*DEC) LEN(3 0) VALUE(20)           
    DCL        VAR(&KEYS) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(20)                       
    DCL        VAR(&SNDID) TYPE(*DEC) LEN(3 0) VALUE(0)             
    DCL        VAR(&SND) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(10) VALUE(' ')             

    CALL       PGM(QRCVDTAQ) PARM(&DTAQ &LIB &LENQ &MSGDTA + 
                   &WAIT &ORDER &KEYLEN &KEYS &SNDID &SND)
    END:                
    RCLRSC  
    ENDPGM   



   //C# Source


   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using cwbx;
   using System.Data.Odbc;


   namespace as400testconsole
   {
   class QRCVDTAQ
   {
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    string connectionStringODBC = "Driver={Client Access ODBC Driver 
    (32-bit)};System=XXXXX;UID=DPSGIT;PWD=abcd1234;";
    GetQueuesCWBX(connectionStringODBC);
    Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static void GetQueuesCWBX(string connectionString)
    {
    string result = String.Empty;
    cwbx.StringConverter stringConverter = new cwbx.StringConverter();
    cwbx.PackedConverter packedConverter = new cwbx.PackedConverter();

    //Define an AS400 system and connect to it
    AS400System system = new AS400System();
    system.Define("XXXXX");
    system.UserID = "XXXXX";
    system.Password = "abcd1234";
    system.IPAddress = "10.144.151.205";
    system.Connect(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceDataQueues);

    //check the connection
    if (system.IsConnected(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceDataQueues) == 
    1)
    {
        //Create a program object and link to a system
        cwbx.Program program = new cwbx.Program();
        program.LibraryName = "XXXXXXXX";
        program.ProgramName = "TEST9100CY";
        program.system = system;

        cwbx.DataQueue dq = new cwbx.DataQueue();
        dq.system = system;
        dq.LibraryName = "XXXXXXXX";
        dq.QueueName = "DQKEY1";

        string dqname = "DQKEY1";
        string lib = "XXXXXXXX";
        string len = "X'01024F'";
        string data = "";
        string wait = "X'00005F'";

        string order = "EQ";
        string keylen = "20";
        string key = "00110736";
        string sendlen = "0";
        string send = "";


        string strSQL = "CALL XXXXXXXX.TEST9100CY 
        ('DQKEY1','XXXXXXXX','DATA','00110736')";


        //Create a collection of parameters associated with the program
        ProgramParameters parameters = new ProgramParameters();
        parameters.Append("DTAQ", cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcInput, 
        10);
        parameters.Append("LIB", cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcInput, 10);
        parameters.Append("MSGDTA", cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcOutput, 
        1024);                           
        parameters.Append("KEYS", cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcInout, 8); 
        parameters["DTAQ"].Value = 
        stringConverter.ToBytes(dqname.PadRight(10, ' '));
        parameters["LIB"].Value = 
        stringConverter.ToBytes(lib.PadRight(10, ' '));
        packedConverter.Digits = 5;
        packedConverter.DecimalPosition = 0;                 
        packedConverter.Digits = 3;
        packedConverter.DecimalPosition = 0;                 
        parameters["KEYS"].Value = 
        stringConverter.ToBytes(key.PadRight(20, ' '));


        //Finally call the program
        try
        {
           program.Call(parameters);
           result = 
           stringConverter.FromBytes(parameters["MSGDTA"].Value);
           Console.WriteLine(result);


           Console.WriteLine(result);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
         {
            if (system.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (cwbx.Error error in system.Errors)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(error.Text);
                    result = error.Text;
                }
            }
            if (program.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (cwbx.Error error in program.Errors)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(error.Text);
                    result += error.Text + "\r\n";
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
        }
        }
        } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the maximum size of an entry in the data queue bigger than 1024?

If so, then the storage following your &MSGDTA variable is probably getting corrupted.

The 3rd parameter of QRCVDTAQ is an output parameter. The API sets that parameter to the length of data it puts in the receiver. The API ignores any value that you put in the parameter.

The 12th parameter in is the parameter where you can tell the API the size of your receiver. If you don't pass the 12th parameter, and the entry returned by the API is longer than 1024, then the storage after the receiver will get corrupted. If that storage happens to be one of the other parameters to the API, the API could get confused while it is running.